# How to find which property of object contains specific value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to loop through an object array using JavaScript and find a specific value, and determine which of the properties is the one that has that value. For example:

Array:

```
var objArray = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Kathy",
    "Position": "Programer",
    "Hobbies": "Computers",
    "Car": "Mustang"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Programing",
    "Hobbies": "Fishing",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Sales",
    "Hobbies": "Programing",
    "Car": "Audi"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "William",
    "Position": "Marketing",
    "Hobbies": "Movies",
    "Car": "Corvette"
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "Stephanie",
    "Position": "Director",
    "Hobbies": "Jogging",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
  }
];
```

Let's say I want to find any value that contains `Program`:

JavaScript:

```
function findMe(array, value) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (String(Object.values(array[i])).indexOf(value) >= 0) {
      results.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

var obj = findMe(objArray, 'Program');
```

So far that works just find, `obj` is loaded with all entries that contain the substring `Program`.

This is my issue, how can I determine which one of the properties of the array is the one that contains the value?

In this case: There a two `Position`s and one `Hobbies` that contain the value `Program`.

Comment: You can use `filter()`: `var obj = objArray.filter(e => e.Name == "John");`

Comment: That downvote was pretty quick. I'm not looking for Name. The value could be contained anywhere in the Name, Position, Hobbies, etc. That's why I'm using Object.values

Comment: @cubanGuy, How do you pretend to store the property which contains the value. Please provide an example of desired output. Currently you return in the `findMe` func the array with all entries that contain the substring you are looking for. So how do you want to modify it in order to know the property that contains it? We need to know that in order to help you.

Comment: @cubanGuy I showed how to check a specific property, which is how I interpreted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my issue, how can I determine which one of the properties of the array is the one that contains the value?

This should be do what you want:

```js
var objArray = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Kathy",
    "Position": "Programer",
    "Hobbies": "Computers",
    "Car": "Mustang"
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Programing",
    "Hobbies": "Fishing",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
},
{
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Sales",
    "Hobbies": "Programing",
    "Car": "Audi"
},
{
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "William",
    "Position": "Marketing",
    "Hobbies": "Movies",
    "Car": "Corvette"
},
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "Stephanie",
    "Position": "Director",
    "Hobbies": "Jogging",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
}];

var foundObjects = [];

for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++)
    for(var j in objArray[i])
    {
        if((''+objArray[i][j]).indexOf('Program') >= 0)
            foundObjects.push({objIndex: i, propertyIndex: j});
    }


for(i = 0; i < foundObjects.length; i++)
{
    var obj = foundObjects[i];
    console.log('Word "Program" was found by object with index: ' + obj.objIndex + ' in the property: ' + obj.propertyIndex);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, decompose a little by adding a function that finds a substring in an object's values.

Next, programming problems are often about clearly describing the desired output.  How about this for a suggested spec: Return an array corresponding to the input array.  The returned array contains -- for each object in the input -- an array of keys where a given string occurs as a substring.

```js
// answer the set of keys in object whose string values contain substring
function propsWhoseValueContains(object, substring) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(key => {
        let value = object[key];
        return (typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf(substring) >= 0);
    });
}

// return an array of arrays.  the inner arrays are keys in the source array's
// objects where value appears as a substring of the objects' values

function findMe(array, value) {
    return array.map(object => propsWhoseValueContains(object, value));
}

var objArray = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Kathy",
    "Position": "Programer",
    "Hobbies": "Computers",
    "Car": "Mustang"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Programing",
    "Hobbies": "Fishing",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "John",
    "Position": "Sales",
    "Hobbies": "Programing",
    "Car": "Audi"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "William",
    "Position": "Marketing",
    "Hobbies": "Movies",
    "Car": "Corvette"
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "Stephanie",
    "Position": "Director",
    "Hobbies": "Jogging",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
  }
];

console.log(findMe(objArray,"Program"));
```